# Async behaviour of alert dialog - Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Ok. Before anyone point me that this is a duplicate, I know it has been asked many times already. But I cannot adopt any of the answers given in those questions. I have alert dialog in a function which has to return a boolean after the user makes a choice in the alert dialog. I cannot modify the boolean value inside the onclick because I have a binary which is dependent on the return value of this function. Can anybody give me any ideas on how to do this?

```
public static boolean allow(){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setView(text);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                result = true;

                if (checked) {
                    p.addapp(pkgname, applicationName, 1, byte);
                }

                dialog.dismiss();

                act.finish();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                result = false;
                if (checked) {
                    p.addapp(pkgname, applicationName, 2, byte);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                act.finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
        dlg.show(); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

So far, I have tried to do it in async, create a new activity for dialog and instantiate it with startActivityForResult(). Also tried to put wait(),notify() but doesnt work. I hope I may get a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. Don't return the choice boolean in the function allow(). Return the boolean and evaluate them after the Dialog onClick event.

Can't you do this?

```
void okay() {
    // place code here
    if (checked) {
        p.addapp(pkgname, applicationName, 1, byte);
    }
}    

void cancel() {
    // place code here
    if (checked) {
        p.addapp(pkgname, applicationName, 2, byte);
    }
}

public static void allow(){
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setView(text);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Allow", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

            okay();

            dialog.dismiss();

            act.finish();

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Deny", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

            cancel();

            dialog.dismiss();
            act.finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
    dlg.show(); 
}
}
```

Comment: how would I do that? The onclick method is void and return statement will cause error inside it right? I dont understand...could you post a small example? Thanks

Comment: I think I was not clear in my question. The if(checked) is not the issue. The real issue is with return result; It always return false and thus the binary always gives a false response. So what I need is, the function must return a value based on user press from dialog.

Comment: Then you have problem in your design because it can't be done like what you want. The response event must be fired from the dialog button.

Comment: That is what I want to know. Atleast how to return the value of the function from inside the onclick. That way, I can ignore the first return and consider the second return value in my binary.